# CakePHP: full path behind link, can't remove?

Tags: cakephp

Seems simple but I can't figure it out. Every link on my website suddenly shows the path behind the link

Example:
Not a member yet? Please register(/users/register) to add your pitch.

I can't select the path with Firebug to trace where it is coming from. Anyone has an idea? Thanks

UPDATE:

The PHP code for this link is:

```
echo $html->link('register', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action'=>'register'));
```

I use the BluePrint CSS Framework

Comment: Post the PHP code of a link that's doing this.

Comment: <?php echo $html->link('register', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action'=>'register')); ?>

Comment: I copied / pasted your code into mine, and it worked fine without the extra text after - maybe a setting changed somewhere?  Sorry I'm not of more help.  Minor note - I think controller should be lowercase, and should be $this->Html->link()   if in 1.3

Comment: You should accept an answer or mark your own as correct (which it isn't, you shouldn't have a print stylesheet affecting screen styles, but you do since you forgot the media attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the style rule. Your problem is that you are linking a print only stylesheet from blueprint as a normal (screen, projection) stylesheet.

You need to make sure your css link has 'media' = 'print' as one of it's attributes.

IE

```
<?php
    ....
    echo $this->Html->css( array(
        join( DS, array( 'blueprint', 'print' )),
        'stylesheet',
        array( 'media' => 'print' )
    );
    ...
?>
```

Somewhere in the head section of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$this->Html->link(__('register', true), array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'register'));
```

cakePHP v. 1.3

Comment: I found the solution, on line 29 of print.css in the webroot/blueprint CSS folder, I removed this line:a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}